# end description item with a dot

Tags: labels, description

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[it 1] description 1
\item[ittt 2] description 2
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

which renders:

[image]

Is there a way to tail automatically "it 1" and "ittt 2" with a dot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\descriptionlabel` controls the format of the `description` label. Its default definition, which you can find in ll. 438-439 of `report.cls`, is

```
\newcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries #1}
```

You can include a period and make it read

```
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                   \normalfont\bfseries #1.}
```

[image: **it 1.** description 1//**ittt 2.** description 2]

---

If applied in the preamble this change is global and affects all `description` environments. If you want to change only one environment you can keep the redefinition local with grouping

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep
  \normalfont\bfseries #1.}
\begin{description}
\item[it 1] description 1
\item[ittt 2] description 2
\end{description}
\endgroup
```

---

If you are using `enumitem` something like

```
\newcommand*\dotteddescriptionlabel[1]{%
  \normalfont\bfseries #1.}
```

in the preamble and then

```
\begin{description}[format=\dotteddescriptionlabel]
\item[it 1] description 1
\item[ittt 2] description 2
\end{description}
```

would also work since `format` may take an argument. Indeed

```
\newcommand*\dotteddescriptionlabel[1]{#1.}
```

would have been enough since the remaining format settings are inherited from the standard `\dotteddescriptionlabel`.

Comment: +1, but it might be useful to note that this changes all `description` environments to have a period after the label.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, added a short comment about that. Thanks for the hint.